# Probability of a particle that is in a particular position

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

When I try to find probability of a particle I just take the product of the complex conjugate of the wavefunction and wavefunction itself, and find the integral from $- \infty$ to $\infty$ or any given range.  What happens if anyone tells me to find the probability at  a particular point?

For example a square well has a length L and I want to find the particle at $\frac{L}{4}$, how to do this?

What I put the  limit is that,  $\frac{L}{4} + \epsilon$ to $\frac{L}{4} - \epsilon$ and i got some result. The problem is that, i can not get away from the $\epsilon$ although i put the limit $\epsilon \to 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the probability of finding a particle at some single point is zero (unless the probability density includes delta-functions or something like that). If you get a different result, there is an error in your calculations.

Comment: I get multiplication of $\epsilon$ , so if i put the value of that is to zero then yes, the probability  value would be zero.

Comment: @SabbirHasan: So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I understand right now :)

Answer (score 1):

Physically, we always ask about the probability of a particle to be located in a *range* of position values. Recall that the probability to find the particle between points $x_1$ and $x_2$ is

$$\int_{x_1}^{x^2} |\Psi(x)|^2 dx.$$

For $x_1=x_2$, the probability is zero. Therefore, the correct question to ask is about the probability of the particle being in a range of $x$ values. In that case, compute the integral above.

NOTE that your $\Psi$ function must be normalized, that is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\Psi(x)|^2 dx=1.$$

Answer (score -3):

The probability of finding a particle in a position $x$ ($x=a/4$) is equal to the probability density: put $x$ for example $a/4$ in  $\left|\psi\right| ^2$. It is wrong to say it is equal to $0$.